# Google cache: texts are on each other

Tags: caching, seo, google-search

[My site](http://www.crea-szkola.pl/) – I have a unusual slider with texts and images.

Check how Google sees it: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.crea-szkola.pl/&hl=en&strip=1

Is it a problem for Google bots that texts are on each other?
Can I get banned for that?

Answer (score 0):

The server at www.crea-szkola.pl can't be found because the DNS look-up failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

You should talk to your hosting team to fix that issue.